# Kotlin: strip first and last character

Tags: kotlin, substring

In Kotlin, I need to strip the first and last characters from a string. This seems to be getting compile errors:

```
val MyPiece = str.substring(0, str.length - 1)
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: what compile error? There is no compile error, unless you dont have str defined. https://pl.kotl.in/TeuDY5asw, and to strip the first char you need to start with 1, not 0

Answer (score 9):

You can also do:

```
val str = "hello"
val myPiece = str.drop(1).dropLast(1)
println(myPiece)
```

Comment: This creates an intermediate string after the call to `drop(1)`. You don't want to be doing this inside a performance-critical loop. `substring(1, str.length - 1)` creates only a single string.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this one:

```
val str = "myText"
var myPiece = str.substring(1, str.length -1)

print(myPiece)
```

Answer (score 0):

Example : 1

```
    String loginToken = "[hello]";
    System.out.println( loginToken.substring( 1, loginToken.length() - 1 ) );
```

Output :

```
hello
```

Answer (score 0):

Care needs to be taken in case the first or last character is an emoji:

```
fun main() {
    val str = "xyz"
    println(
        str.substring(
            if (str.first().isSurrogate()) 2 else 1,
            str.length - if (str.last().isSurrogate()) 2 else 1
        )
    )
}
```

Output:

```
xyz
```

The other answers don't work with surrogate pairs, and return "?xyz?".